# XSL copy everything and replace

Tags: xml, xslt

INPUT XML:

```
<root>
<output_getquerydata>
    <query name="test">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="id">TS1</parameter>
        </parameters>
        <results>
            <record>
                <column name="address">VAL1</column>
            </record>
        </results>
    </query>
</output_getquerydata>
<output_getquerydata>
    <query name="test">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="id">TS2</parameter>
        </parameters>
        <results>
            <record>
                <column name="address">VAL2</column>
            </record>
        </results>
    </query>
</output_getquerydata>
<node>
    <CTO>
        <id>TRFG2</id>
        <order_number>TRFG2</order_number>
        <PT>
            <address>
                <id>C248355-91862</id>
                <code>T-48-KS-3659-SHELL BR</code>
            </address>
            <reference/>
            <comment/>
        </PT>
        <DT>
            <address>
                <id>C1050692</id>
                <code>C1050692</code>
            </address>
            <comment>This is a comment.</comment>
        </DT>
        <OLS>
            <OL>
                <id>TS1</id>
                <PT/>
                <DT>
                    <station>
                        <id>C1050692-01</id>
                        <code>C1050692-01</code>
                        <addressId>C1050692</addressId>
                    </station>
                </DT>
            </OL>
            <OL>
                <id>TS2</id>
                <PT/>
                <DT>
                    <station>
                        <id>C1050692-01</id>
                        <code>C1050692-01</code>
                        <addressId>C1050692</addressId>
                    </station>
                </DT>
            </OL>
        </OLS>
    </CTO>
</node>
</root>
```

CURRENT XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CTO/PT/address"/>
<!--exclude-->
<xsl:template match="CTO/OLS/OL/PT">
    <PT>
        <addressId>
            <!--each OL ID-->
            <xsl:variable name="OLID">
                <xsl:value-of select="/../OL/id"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!--select the column value where the query parameter ID matches the OL id-->
            <xsl:value-of select="//output_getquerydata/query[parameters/parameter[@name='id']=$OLID]/results/record/column[@name='address']"/>
        </addressId>
    </PT>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="output_getquerydata"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
 <node>
 <!--1. copy everything-->
<CTO>
    <id>TRFG2</id>
    <order_number>TRFG2</order_number>
    <!--2. exclude address tag here-->
    <PT>
        <reference/>
        <comment/>
    </PT>
    <DT>
        <address>
            <id>C1050692</id>
            <code>C1050692</code>
        </address>
        <comment>This is a comment.</comment>
    </DT>
    <OLS>
        <OL>
            <!--3. match OL ID-->
            <id>TS1</id>
            <PT>
                <!--4. and add here the value from the outputquery result-->
                <addressId>VAL1</addressId>
            </PT>
            <DT>
                <station>
                    <id>C1050692-01</id>
                    <code>C1050692-01</code>
                    <addressId>C1050692</addressId>
                </station>
            </DT>
        </OL>
        <OL>
            <id>TS2</id>
            <PT>
                <addressId>VAL2</addressId>
            </PT>
            <DT>
                <station>
                    <id>C1050692-01</id>
                    <code>C1050692-01</code>
                    <addressId>C1050692</addressId>
                </station>
            </DT>
        </OL>
    </OLS>
</CTO>
</node>
```

The goal is to copy everything and then do the following:
1. exclude the CTO/PT/address tag, do not copy it in the output
2. for each OLS/OL/ID add under OLS/OL/PT/addressID the value from the query/results tag, where the query/parameter ID matches the OLS/OL/ID.
In my case, for the OL with ID= TS 1, i need to add under PT/addressID the value of VAL1 (taken from the query/results that has the query/parameter ID = TS1)

I've tried to define a variable that saves the OL ID and then the XSL value will select the appropriate query. But I am not sure what I am doing wrong, probably because of the template match, that positions me in that specific position and can't match properly.

Can somebody please help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define a key for the cross-reference:

```
<xsl:key name="query" match="output_getquerydata/query/results/record/column[@name = 'address']" use="ancestor::query/parameters/parameter[@name = 'id']"/>
```

then it is easy to pull in that value, the rest you seem to have done fine:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CTO/PT/address"/>

<xsl:key name="query" match="output_getquerydata/query/results/record/column[@name = 'address']" use="ancestor::query/parameters/parameter[@name = 'id']"/>

<xsl:template match="CTO/OLS/OL/PT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <addressId>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('query', ../id)"/>
        </addressId>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="output_getquerydata"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaF9

Comment: thank you, this works. one question : my input starts with <root>, in my output i only want the <node> to be the main parent tag, how would i do this?

Comment: Add a template `<xsl:template match="/root"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>`.